# What are the differences between 4 Wacom's Intuos tablets?

Tags: drawing-tablet, wacom

On [Wacom's site](http://www.wacom.com/en-br/products/pen-tablets/intuos) there are 4 Intuos tablets listed: Draw, Art, Photo and Comic. They all look the same except for the border color. From the description it seems like they have subtle important differences which would matter for specific usage patterns, but it's not clear what they are. What are the differences between these 4 models?

Comment: [Anecdotally empty comparison on their store page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3K4l.png)

Comment: Review the "tech specs" for each tablet.

Comment: @Scott the site has changed since this question was posted

Comment: Not really... click a version, then click "specifications" -- compare..

Comment: @Scott yes really! The site is different now from November 29 of the year 2016.

Answer (score 2):

The cheaper Draw tablet does not have touch functions. The difference between the other 3 models is only the colors offered and the bundled software. The actual functionality of the tablet is the same.

Answer (score -1):

they are all the same , the only difference is the bundle software they provide with different models.

Comment: that was already said in the other answer.